# From dictionary, return key based on percentage chance

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have a dictionary made up of strings and a percent chance of their appearance, like so:

```
{"a": 0.2, "b": 0.6, "c": 0.1, "d": 0.1}
```

How would I make it so it returns `"a" 20% of the time`, `"b" 60% of the time`, and `"c" and "d" each 10% of the time`?

Answer (score 1):

You need `random.choices`

```
import random
x = {"a": 0.2, "b": 0.6, "c": 0.1, "d": 0.1}
print(random.choices(list(x.keys()), list(x.values()), k=1)[0])
```

**Edit**

To make it reusable write a function:

```
def get_number(x):
    return random.choices(list(x.keys()), list(x.values()), k=1)[0]

import random
x = {"a": 0.2, "b": 0.6, "c": 0.1, "d": 0.1}
print(get_number(x))
```

In `random.choices`

1. 1st parameter is a list of values that should be returned
2. 2nd parameter is weight(or probability) of generating the values passed in param

Answer (score 0):

Try my solution:

```
st = {"a": 0.2, "b": 0.6, "c": 0.1, "d": 0.1}
g = dict((x, str(int(st[x] * 100)) + "% of the time") for x in st)
print(g)

{'a': '20% of the time', 'b': '60% of the time', 'c': '10% of the time', 'd': '10% of the time'}
```